# How do I setup visual studio to register some #defines globally?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, c-preprocessor

What I mean is, in each of my source files I have to insert #define NOGDI to stop windows.h from including GDI defines (since it's BITMAP define conflicts with mine).

e.g.

```
#define NOGDI
#include <windows.h>
```

Unfortunately, I have to do this in every seperate source file which includes windows.h, which I do not want to do.
I am using Visual Studio 2005, is there any way I can set it to #define something globally? (i.e. in all of the source files).

Comment: Besides tenfour's answer, you can create something like config.h (that contains your favourite #define), then include this file in your source code :)

Comment: This question shows up among first entries while googling for global defines in msvs. So for MSVS 2019 is there a way to define something like `#define INT(X) static_cast<int>(X)` globally?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Project Settings -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor definitions

Here you can define symbols that are applied globally to all source code in your project.

Comment: @user631623: If this was helpful and answered your question, you should accept it as the correct answer by clicking the green check mark next to it.

Comment: @adam: Yea, he replied very quickly and it did not allow me to select a correct answer that fast, so I totally forgot about it, sorry.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, at least as far as I can tell. Is there a new way for VS2015?

Comment: for Atmel Studio 7 which is derived from Visual Studio, you'll find the option at: "[Project Properties] (rightclick on project in project explorer) -> Toolchain -> YourCopiler Compiler" -> Symbols, hit the add-button and set e.g. F_CPU=8000000UL

Comment: (At least in msvs 2019) I could only define symbols, like conditional, but not macros with symbols having an actual value.

Answer (score 6):

I had set up the needed define for whole project, as described, in
Project Settings -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor definitions

But nevertheless this didn't work!

Eventually it turned out that problem was in checked NoInherit checkbox,
"Inherit from parent or project defaults"

In defines' line of Preprocessor Definitions Dialog it's seen as: 
WIN32;_DEBUG;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;$(NoInherit)

Checked the thing back and the define finally recognized.

Comment: I found for some reason ubchecking, applying, and then rechecking this option solved my issue.  I have no idea why.

Comment: sometimes trying to rebuild the project helps. if it still does not work restarting VS helps.

Answer (score 1):

For VS2015 I edited the `.vcxproj` file and added a section such as this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">  
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>      
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>MY_VARIABLE=SOMETHING</PreprocessorDefinitions>
```