# Declare Preprocessor Definitions without editing the ".vcxproj" file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, preprocessor

Is there a way to declare preprocessor definitions without editing the ".vcxproj" file in Visual Studio 2015?

Could it be possible to pass the definitions directly to the compiler?

Comment: You can [use the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100283/how-do-i-setup-visual-studio-to-register-some-defines-globally) to do it, but besides that I doubt it - the `.vcxproj` file is designed to store the settings of the project, and preprocessor definitions come under that heading, so it's unlikely there'll be settings elsewhere. What's the reason? There may be other ways of resolving a problem.

Comment: I'm using a version control software to store the files and I want to declare this definition just once for testing. If I add the definitions in the UI, it's very likely that I will forget to delete them and add them to the version control software.

Comment: The vcxproj files are XML, and IIRC they are stored in a stable fashion, so that the changes will be easy to catch in the diffs. You do audit the diffs before committing, right?